# WP show shortcode in description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem... I using plugin Display Product for WooCommerce which show products in list view with description. But in these descriptions I have a tables with shortcode [table]...but this tables is not rendered, because description is rendered in raw html format.

How can I change this line of code to show also content from shortcodes?

```
    if ($excerpt == 'show') {
        $result.= '<p>' . wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $trimwords ) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html result of the table shortcode by executing

```
$tableHTML = do_shortcode('[table]');
```

And subsequently append that HTML to the result.